# Avoiding confusion with the word "before"

Tags: prepositions

I wrote this sentence:

> I do not trust what has been written before me.

Now, I was trying to use 'before' in the sense of 'prior to,' but just realized that 'before me' might also be taken to mean 'in front of me.' What might be a better way to reword this? I have thought of omitting 'me'--would that be correct?

Answer (score 3):

You could say:

- *I don't trust what has been written previously*
- *I don't trust what has already been written*
- *I don't trust what has been written before* ( without me)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I do not trust what has been written **before me**.

with 'me' as the object pronoun. But consider that 'before' can also work with a subject pronoun.

> I do not trust what has been written **before I was born**.

I think in your case, you may find the subject pronoun works better.

My preference:

> I do not trust what <s>has been</s> was written **before I was born**.